# how to add one on name attribute with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic form section which I need the name attribute to be dynamic as well.
the number should always get +1 each time the user create a new section !

name="training**[1](https://jsfiddle.net/n4dftou5/2/)**[institut]"

This is crucial to have a proper SQL insert ... otherwise the array won't have a classical database logics !

[JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/n4dftou5/2/)

Any idea ? thanks a lot from France !

```
    <form method="post" action="">

    <!-- INFO SECTION -->
    <div id="infos">
        <h2>Infos personnelles</h2>
        <input placeholder="Prénom">
        <input placeholder="Nom">     
    </div>


    <!-- TRAINING SECTION -->
    <div id="training">
        <h2>Formation</h2>
        <!-- Template -->
        <div id="new-training" style="display:none">
            <div>
                    </br>
                    <p></p>
                    <input id="mytext" type="text" name="training[1][institut]" placeholder="Diplôme" value="">
                    <input name="training[1][institut]" placeholder="Institut">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="addnew">
        <a href="javascript:addTraining()">+ Ajouter une formation</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sauvergarder" name="submit">
    </p>
</form>


<script> // 1st : Enregistrer / supprimer une formation

var ct = 1;

function addTraining()
{
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;
    // link to delete extended form elements
    var delLink = '<a href="javascript:removeTraining('+ ct +')">Supprimer cette formation</a>';
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('new-training').innerHTML + delLink;
    document.getElementById('training').appendChild(div1);
}

function removeTraining(eleId)
{
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('training');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem..

Comment: @DanielTran sorry, it was a bit unclear. I have just edited the post ! I cant' make the name attribute dynamic ! That's my point. I've been struggling hours with it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution (my opinion) is to use a simple templating engine

https://jsfiddle.net/nget5dq2/1/

Addition to your HTML:

```
<template id="new_el_template" hidden>
  <div id="row-{cid}">
    <input id="mytext-{cid}" type="text" name="training[{cid}][institut]" placeholder="Diplôme" value="">
    <input name="training[{cid}][institut]" placeholder="Institut">
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:removeTraining({cid})">Supprimer cette formation</a>
</template>
```

JS

```
var ct = 1;
function addTraining() {
    ct++;              
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('new_el_template').innerHTML.replace(/\{cid\}/gi, ct);
    document.getElementById('training').appendChild(div);
}
function removeTraining(eleId) {
   document.getElementById('row-' + eleId).parentNode.remove();
}
```

And yes, you can go ahead and generate the initial element directly from the template.

Comment: Thank a lot @Unbywyd ! Your piece of code looks DRY ! However the Remove function broke during the code upgrade. Tried to solve it by creating a div with the "training" id in the template ... but without success. Any clue ?

Comment: Delete is just not a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/s9rquj1L/ but if you need to reset the counter, it requires rendering full rows

Comment: Again, if not all rows are deleted, and if all, then you can ask the counter for 0

Comment: I owe you a coffee bro ;) Works perfect !

Answer (score 0):

write the `name` attribute this way you should get all the data from the form when u post it.

```js
 <input id="mytext" type="text" name="training[diploma][]" placeholder="Diplôme" value="">
 <input name="training[institut][]" placeholder="Institut">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with comments added throughout..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="post" action="">

    <!-- INFO SECTION -->
    <div id="infos">
        <h2>Infos personnelles</h2>
        <input placeholder="Prénom">
        <input placeholder="Nom">     
    </div>


    <!-- TRAINING SECTION -->
    <div id="training">
        <h2>Formation</h2>
        <!-- Template -->
        <div id="new-training" >
            <div>
                    </br>
                    <p></p>
                    <input id="mytext" type="text" name="training[1][institut]" placeholder="Diplôme" value="">
                    <input name="training[1][institut]" placeholder="Institut">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p id="addnew">
        <a style="color: blue" onclick="addTraining()">+ Ajouter une formation</a>
    </p>

    <p>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sauvergarder" name="submit">
    </p>
</form>



</body>



    
<script>
    

    const addTraining = () => {
        
        //Get parent container to place new input into
        const parent = document.getElementById('training');


        //Create DIV to wrap around input elements
        let div = document.createElement('div')
        
        //Create new input with a unique name attribute
        let newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
        let newInput2 = document.createElement('input');

        //You can get an array of all existing elements and add 1 to create a unique name for each
        let num = parent.querySelectorAll('div').length + 1,
            newName = 'training['+ num +'][institut]';      
        
        //Set name attribute
        newInput1.setAttribute('name', newName);
        newInput2.setAttribute('name', newName);

        //Set other attributes you alreadt had
        newInput1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Diplôme');
        newInput2.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Institut');
        newInput1.setAttribute('id', 'myText');
        newInput1.setAttribute('type', 'text');

        //Append elements
        parent.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(newInput1);
        div.appendChild(newInput2)


    }


</script>

</html>
```